# CSS expand table width when using max-width

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this has to be simple but I just can't figure it out. I have a HTML table with a number of columns. The text in some of those columns can be quite long. I'm trying to use max-width to set the maximum width of the column to a certain value.

The problem is that the width of the column does not grow to its max-width setting but seems to be restricted by the width of the table. See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d44pu2jy/1/). This is the CSS...

```
    .ReportTableItem TD
{
    color: Black;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    max-width:550px !important; 
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Your max width is currently 550px, which itself is a lot per column.have a look at this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/d44pu2jy/3/) . Are you looking at applying a max width to the whole table like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gzd7yaaL/)?

Comment: you replace the max-width to min-width in css and see the ouput

Comment: I've got it to work for one row but no the column alignments are all out of whack. See [link](https://jsfiddle.net/d44pu2jy/5/)

Comment: @SatejS I'm looking to set the max-width of the columns, not the entire table.

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati I cannot use min-width becuase it will affect all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use "min-width" instead of "max-width".

Comment: This won't really solve the problem, especially on a smaller screen.

Comment: For this type of table, especially on a smaller screen we need to put horizontal scrollbar or need to change design like al column will converted into row.

Comment: Absolutely!That's why we can't use min-width, else we'll have to write media queries for overflow in smaller resolutions.

Comment: min-width will affect all columns. I only want the column to reach max-width if there is enough text there. If the column has only a small amount of text, then the column width should be less than max-width.

Comment: @SadikaliDanntreliya How would I put in a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Put one div as parent of table with class "table-outer" and put css as below : 

.table-outer{overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden;}

Comment: @SadikaliDanntreliya Thanks but it still doesn't solve the problem. The text in the column wraps before the max-width is reached.

Comment: I have done some modification in your code, check now :

https://jsfiddle.net/d44pu2jy/8/

Comment: @SadikaliDanntreliya Thanks but that is not really what I'm looking for. The width of the columns should be set according to the text inside the column up until it reaches the max-width. Not all columns will reach the max-width. In such a case, the column width should be smaller than the max-width. See [this] (https://jsfiddle.net/d44pu2jy/9/)